# age filter in django

Tags: django, filter

I have products in my ecommerce. How can I group them in age groups like child, adult, senior? But one product can be on morethan one group. Example a cloth can be for both adult and senior. What method should I choose?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # many to one relation with Category
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    brand = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='images/')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    detail = RichTextUploadingField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Your question needs some code, it's hard to help without knowing the structure of your models, etc.

Comment: I added the product model brother

Answer (score 0):

You will want a many-to-many field to a Category, like so:

```py
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...
   ...

class Product(models.Model):
   categories = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, ...
   ...
```

You can then assign products to any number of product categories. You will access them like so:

```py
# get categories from a product
product.categories.all()

# get product from categories
category.product_set.all()
```